# pgrep exact matching with a PID file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a process ID stored in a .pid file.

I want the `pgrep` command to find out whether that process is running or not. I tried using the flags `pgrep -xF file.pid` but I'm still getting a regex match (which is what I do not want).

Is there any way to get an exact match?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing it wrong. Use `kill -0`.

Comment: `kill -0 $(cat file.pid)` will give me the appropriate exit code for whether the process is running or not?

Comment: writing this comment should took less your energy than actually checking it :). If exit code is '0' and there is no any message like `kill: kill 1234 failed: no such process` - process is working.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify what OS you are on, but on Linux, an alternative to `kill -0` would be to check for the existence of a directory named `/proc/<pid>`. That will work for desktop/laptop distributions (at least all the ones I've ever used), but may not on some embedded platforms where support for the `/proc` file system is not included in the kernel.